# currency not changing

Tags: currency, multicurrency, magento-1.9.1.1

I have 3 currencies setup on my page GBP, EUR and USD.

The default is USD.
When I click on either GBP or EUR currency the page reloads but stays on USD, also all prices stay on USD.

I have tried to empty the cache and reindex but both won't help.

I don't know what to look for now, anyone have a pointer what could be the issue?

Comment: Are you changing the base currency or the store currency?

Comment: I am changing the currency on the home page as a visitor of the webpage.

Comment: So you have a single store with 3 currencies?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.